# Angular material table change row color

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to know if it is possible to change row Color depending on date order,

I have a field in the table (mat table)  which is a date, and I want the row with the closest date to be red till green for the furthest date .

Comment: For a similar need, I ended up writing a custom directive.  But I think you might have to do the math outside of the data model and add an indicator into the model, then the directive would just be to highlight the color if X = 1 or something.  I didn't do this for mat-table, but I "think" it's basically the same thing.

Comment: Seems pretty simple. You should be able to set your <tr> background color based on where in the range your date falls

Answer (score 1):

in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367010/average-2-hex-colors-together-in-javascript) you has how mix two colors. So if you defined a function

```
  blendColors(colorA:string, colorB:string, amount:number) {
    const [rA, gA, bA] = (colorA.match(/\w\w/g) || []).map((c) => parseInt(c, 16));
    const [rB, gB, bB] = (colorB.match(/\w\w/g) || []).map((c) => parseInt(c, 16));
    const r = Math.round(rA + (rB - rA) * amount).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
    const g = Math.round(gA + (gB - gA) * amount).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
    const b = Math.round(bA + (bB - bA) * amount).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
    return '#' + r + g + b;
  }
```

You can use [style.background-color] in the `<tr mat-row>`

```
  <tr mat-row 
    [style.background-color]="blendColors('#FF0000','#00FF00',i/dataSource.length)"
      *matRowDef="let row; let i=index; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </tr>
```

well this colored the background from red to green from top to down, Really I'm not prety sure you want to say "the row with the closest date to be red till green for the furthest date" but instead i/dataSource.length you can use another property from 0 to 1

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqf29r?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Comment: thanks for the reply really help to get the coolers  well need now the math to sort the dates